# Unable to add event handler for WPF in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, user-controls, telerik

I am trying to add an event handler using Visual Studio-properties, but every time I click on any event (for example I select a button in XAML and try to add `MyButton_Click`) I get a pop-up message saying "Unable to add event handler."

[image: Visual Studio dialog]

user control

```
<UserControl x:Class=" TelerikWpfApp1.Control.ImageControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="316" d:DesignWidth="391">
<Grid>

    <!--<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="70*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>-->
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Border BorderThickness="3" Margin="10" x:Name="border" Background="White" CornerRadius="10" >
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" Height="100" Width="100" />
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect />
                            </Border.Effect>
                            <Border.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Border">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=border, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Border.Style>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Hidden" >
        <Image Source="{Binding SelectedImage.ImageUri}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

    </Border>
</Grid>
```